# Where are the Hive Table/Database settings?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform

i need to find the configuration files in hdfs for a Hive Table. I have found the Table data with "describe formatted ;" but where are the col_name or data_type informations stored?

Answer (score 0):

This is stored in the metastore database, but I would recommend not to edit it directly.

You should use

```
DESCRIBE TABLE mytable;
```

with possible options as advised
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Describe